# Displacement as a function of the force and the properties of the frame I and J

Tags: structures, frame

[image]I was wondering how you would find the stiffness matrix of a triangular frame with unknown angles.

A little context
The pumpjack model involves a triangular frame on which the rocking beam is supported. How would you find an expression for the displacement of the pivot point as a function of the force and the properties of the frame I and J.
[A visual of what I mean]

Comment: If the angles are really unknown, I don't think you can. But is it really so? What do you know about the frame?